# Continue running npm test script after test fails in a bash loop

Tags: bash, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js

I have a few different projects, each with their own unit tests.
I created a bash script that will `cd` into each project and run `npm test` and I would like to do so through all my folders.

This currently looks something like this:

```
ROOT_PATH="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
"${ROOT_PATH}/enter-folders" npm test
```

Where `npm test` is as follows:

> "test": "mocha --require @babel/register --watch-extensions js **/*.test.js",

The `enter-folders` script does what it's title says, it cds into each folder from a list so that I can later run whatever I want in each folder. It looks something like this:

```
while read FOLDER_NAME; do
  PROJECT="${FOLDER_NAME}"
  FOLDER="${BASE_PATH}/${PROJECT}"
  cd "$FOLDER"
  "$@"
  echo ""
```

The problem I am getting is that if in one of the projects, a test doesn't pass my entire script stops. Is there any way to force the script to continue? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Is it stopping because you have `set -e` enabled? If so you can ignore the failure with `"$@" || true`.

Comment: The `set -e` doesn't make a difference. And `"$@" || true` didn't do anything either. Is there any more I can do with them that perhaps I may be missing?

Comment: Update: Sorry I misunderstood the placement of the `"$@"`. That fixed it! Thanks!